# Is there a Java open source library for managing a NISO/ANSI Z39.19 controlled vocabulary in XML or SKOS format?

Tags: xml, parsing, semantic-web, thesaurus

I need a Java library to parse thesauri files which adhere to the [NISO/ANSI Z39.19 standard](https://www.niso.org/publications/ansiniso-z3919-2005-r2010) XML or [SKOS](http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/) format. Parsing these files and creating associated classes to represent the data doesn't seem hard; I'm just trying to avoid reinventing the wheel. Commercial-friendly license ideally. SKOS seems really popular for semantic web applications, so I thought this would exist.

Comment: consider asking on answers.semanticweb.com

Comment: @harschware thanks, I have done so here! http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/8437/is-there-a-java-open-source-library-for-managing-a-nisoansi-z3919-controlled-vocabulary-in-xml-or-skos-format